# Apply PICKER FORMAT on ION-SELECT

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-select

Want the `<ion-select>` to display the options same like `<ion-datetime>`. Like the `pickerFormat`.

I studied both the links from the IONIC documentation.

[ion-datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

[ion-select](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/)

but didn't find any solution that how can I apply the `pickerFormat`  styling of `<ion-datetime>` to `<ion-select>`. It's only accepting the `interface` property as `action-sheet`, `popover` and `alert`.

Can anyone help, please?